# Appending nested elements in Javascript function for HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to append another HTML element to a element in Javascript.

What my function below does is that on the click of the "add" button, whatever the user has typed into a textbox is put into a `ul` element in my menu and a element `li` is created to append that text inside the `li` element. My function works but I also want to append a `a href = #> insert text here</a>` nested inside the `li` element.

So what I have my function doing right now is

```
<ul class = "dropdown-menu">
   <li> User Text </li>
</ul>
```

I want to reproduce this

```
<ul class = "dropdown-menu">
   <li> <a href ="#">User Text</a> </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
 (function() {
  document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let input = document.querySelector('#addissuetext');
    let list = document.querySelector('#menu');

    let item = document.createElement('li'); // create li node
    let hyper = document.createElement('a');
    hyper.href = "#";
    let itemText = document.createTextNode(input.value); // create text node

    item.appendChild(itemText); // append text node to li node
    hyper.appendChild(item);
    list.appendChild(item); // append li node to list

    input.value = ""; // clear input
  });
})();
```

I have also tried innerHTML but I do not think that is what will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append text into anchor first, then append that anchor into li, then li into ul.

`ul > li > a > text`

```
hyper.appendChild(itemText); // append text to anchor

item.appendChild(hyper); // append anchor node to li node

list.appendChild(item); // append li node to list
```

Since you have not provided snippet or full html, this may create some error.

```
(function() {
  document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let input = document.querySelector('#addissuetext');
    let list = document.querySelector('#menu');

    let item = document.createElement('li'); // create li node
    let hyper = document.createElement('a');
    hyper.href = "#";
    let itemText = document.createTextNode(input.value); // create text node


    hyper.appendChild(itemText); // append text to anchor

    item.appendChild(hyper); // append anchor node to li node

    list.appendChild(item); // append li node to list

    input.value = ""; // clear input
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have things in the wrong order:

```
(function () {
    document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function () {
        let input = document.querySelector('#addissuetext');
        let list = document.querySelector('#menu');

        let item = document.createElement('li'); // create li node
        let hyper = document.createElement('a');
        hyper.href = "#";
        let itemText = document.createTextNode(input.value); // create text node

        hyper.appendChild(itemText); // append text node to hyperlink
        item.appendChild(hyper); // append hyperlink to li
        list.appendChild(item); // append li node to list

        input.value = ""; // clear input
    });
})();
```